# How to identify if an observation is repeated every day in Stata

Tags: stata

I have a database where I have a date variable, an id variable and a city variable. Sometimes the id variable is repeated in the same date and city.
Data looks something like this:

> Date        ID     City
>
> > 2/1/2015    1        1
> >
> > 2/1/2015    1        1
> >
> > 2/1/2015    1        2
> >
> > 2/2/2015    1        1
> >
> > 2/1/2015    2        1
> >
> > 2/2/2015    2        1

I would like to know how much days each ID is present, identify the id's that are present every day, and later on, those that are present every day in every city.
In the example above both ID 1&2 are present each day, but only ID 1 is present in each city each day.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think I just did what i wanted to do. 
All I had to do was:

```
by ID city date, sort: gen nvals = _n == 1
by ID city: replace nvals = sum(nvals)
by ID city : replace nvals = nvals[_N]
```

Comment: I think sort is needed first, but hard to say without MWE?

Comment: @radek You're correct that a `sort` is needed first, but that was achieved by the OP's `, sort` so the extra statement you've introduced does no harm but is not needed.

Comment: Ah missed that `sort`! Thanks for spotting @Nick.